# Import component and its properties/methods inside other component

Tags: vue.js

if i have component LogoutButton.vue

```
export default {
  data() 
  {
      return {

      }
      
  },
  methods: 
  { 
    Logout()
    {
        console.log("something")
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
    <button @click="Logout">Logout</button>
</template>
```

How can i use the LogoutButton component inside other component?
I mean how can i import the component and its click methods inside other component?

Comment: [use this](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#using-a-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script>
import LogoutButton from './LogoutButton.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    LogoutButton
  },
  data() 
  {
      return {

      }
      
  },
  methods: 
  { 
    // Your different methods
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <!-- The template from LogoutButton component will display here -->
    <LogoutButton />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: do i have to write again the code from method Logout from LogoutButton component inside of the methods: { // Your different methods} ?

Comment: No, This place is for writing methods related to the component you are writing. I invite you to read the Vue.js documentation to understand how components and their reusability work